# Scipy UnivariateSpline exit code -1073741819 for some case

Tags: python, scipy, spline

I use UnivariateSpline from scipy module to fit data.It works for almost all cases except for this one, which gives rise to `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)` error. If I change smoothing factor `s` to 0, it also works. Any suggestions to solve this problem will help.

---

**Update1**

My working environment is:

- python 3.7
- scipy 1.3.2
- numpy 1.17.4

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline, InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

x = np.arange(78)
y = np.asarray([
 0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,
 0.,         0.,         5.03989319, 4.03191455, 4.03191455, 3.02393591,
 3.02393591, 2.01595727, 2.01595727, 1.00797864, 0.,         0.,
 0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,
 0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,
 0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,
 0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,
 0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,
 0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,
 0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,
 0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,
 0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,
 0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.,         0.])

spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y, k=1, s=0.01)

knots = list(map(int, spl.get_knots()))
plt.plot(knots, y[knots], 'rx')
plt.plot(knots, y[knots], 'r-')
plt.plot(x, y, 'b-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think it's a bug for univariatespline module. With my tests, if I add a samll number  e.g. ``eps=1e-5`` to y then the code works.

Answer (score 0):

The combination of you `s` and `k` parameter are causing the issue.

According to the documentation, the number of knots increases until the condition `sum((w[i] * (y[i]-spl(x[i])))**2, axis=0) <= s` is met. However, because you have a limited number of non-zero data points, you can only add so many meaningful knots to the data set, and because you are doing `k=1` spline (as opposed to cubic for example), the difference between the spline value and the data values is never reaching the prescribed `s` value.

Your options include increasing `k` (I tested with `k=3` and it worked) or increase the `s` value to have a less strict condition (anything above `s=0.08` worked for me). Note your code worked when `s=0` because for that condition, instead of doing a smoothing, the algorithm just interpolates between each point and does no smoothing (which maybe is what you want).

Comment: To some degree, you're right. However, if the univariate spline algorithm doesn't meet the ``sum((w[i] * (y[i]-spl(x[i])))**2, axis=0) <= s`` condition, it will only run 20 iterations (can be seen in ``scipy\interpolate\fitpack2.py->_curfilt_messages``) and return the approximate result.For this case, it exit with no zero code, I think maybe it's due to the algorithm implementation code bug.

Comment: If I append 4 zeros to y, it also works, so maybe not the limited meaningful data points with too small ``s`` cause the exit problem.